# what is the replacement for advapi32.dll (CryptAcquireContext, CryptReleaseContext....) for C#

Tags: c#, api, dll

What is the replacement for the advapi32.dll.
CryptAcquireContext, CryptReleaseContext, CryptCreateHash, CryptDestroyHash, CryptDeriveKey, CryptDestroyKey, CryptEncrypt, CryptDecrypt, CryptHashDataString.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Not much help there on decryption/encrypting registry values

Comment: You are wasting your time with such comments, it belongs in the question.